# Moving a picture out of the body

Tags: html, css, image

Sorry that you have to do this but could you go to this address: http://www.neopets.com/userlookup.phtml?user=coool_xman

I need help with making the top banner (The one that says Krawk) to be out of the "white box" and kind of in its own area. I want the banner to be above the box, so basically just moved 300px up or so and everything else stays the same.

I've tried creating another body, Floats etc but can't figure it out. Here is my code.

```
<style>
body {
background: fixed url("http://i1164.photobucket.com/albums/q565/whitehouses88/PLs/PirateBunk.jpg") no-repeat;
}
hr, #header, #footer, .sf, #ban {
display: none;
}
.contentModuleHeader, .contentModuleHeaderAlt {
font: 18pt tahoma;
color: #261712;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.content div div, .content .contentModule, .contentModuleTable, .contentModule, #main {
border: none;
}
td, body, font, .medText, body, p {
font: 9pt tahoma;
line-height: 12pt;
}
b {
color: #6e231e;
}
i {
color: #261712;
}
a:link, a:visited, a:active, a b {
color: #90714d;
font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover, a:hover b {
color: #261712;
}
#aja {
width: 8px;
}
#navy {
padding: 4px;
margin: 4px;
text-align: center;
}
#navy a {
color: #ffffff !important;
background: #90714d;
display: inline-block;
width: 75px;
padding: 4px;
margin: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font: 9pt trebuchet MS;
font-weight: bold;
}
#navy a:hover {
padding: 4px;
margin: 2px;
background: #6e231e;
}
#main {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border: 10px solid #261712;
}
#userneopets img {
background: #90714d;
padding: 8px;
}
</style>

<table><tr>
<td width="1100" valign="top">
<img src="http://i1327.photobucket.com/albums/u673/Vipersnake94/KrawkIsland2_zps134bd61f.png" width="975" class="special">
</td>
<td width="1100" valign="top">
</td>
</tr></table>
<div id="navy">
<a href="/myaccount.phtml">Account</a><a href="/customise/">Customize</a><a href="/games/arcade.phtml">Games</a><a href="/explore.phtml">Explore</a><a href="/nf.phtml">News</a><a href="/petcentral.phtml">Central</a><a href="/neoboards/index.phtml">Boards</a><a href="/objects.phtml">Shops</a><a href="/mall/index.phtml">Mall</a><a href="/~Sparkle">Credit</a>
</div>
<br><div style="width: 800px;">

</div>
```

---

```
<style>
body {
background: fixed url("http://i1164.photobucket.com/albums/q565/whitehouses88/PLs/PirateBunk.jpg") no-repeat;
}
hr, #header, #footer, .sf, #ban {
display: none;
}
.contentModuleHeader, .contentModuleHeaderAlt {
font: 18pt tahoma;
color: #261712;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.content div div, .content .contentModule, .contentModuleTable, .contentModule, #main {
border: none;
}
td, body, font, .medText, body, p {
font: 9pt tahoma;
line-height: 12pt;
}
b {
color: #6e231e;
}
i {
color: #261712;
}
a:link, a:visited, a:active, a b {
color: #90714d;
font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover, a:hover b {
color: #261712;
}
#aja {
width: 8px;
}
#navy {
padding: 4px;
margin: 4px;
text-align: center;
}
#navy a {
color: #ffffff !important;
background: #90714d;
display: inline-block;
width: 75px;
padding: 4px;
margin: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font: 9pt trebuchet MS;
font-weight: bold;
}
#navy a:hover {
padding: 4px;
margin: 2px;
background: #6e231e;
}
#main {
margin-top: 274px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border: 10px solid #261712;
}
#userneopets img {
background: #90714d;
padding: 8px;
}

img.special { position: absolute; top: 0; }

</style>

<table><tr>
<td width="1100" valign="top">
<img src="http://i1327.photobucket.com/albums/u673/Vipersnake94/KrawkIsland2_zps134bd61f.png" width="975" class="special">
</td>
<td width="1100" valign="top">
</td>
</tr></table>
<div id="navy">
<a href="/myaccount.phtml">Account</a><a href="/customise/">Customize</a><a href="/games/arcade.phtml">Games</a><a href="/explore.phtml">Explore</a><a href="/nf.phtml">News</a><a href="/petcentral.phtml">Central</a><a href="/neoboards/index.phtml">Boards</a><a href="/objects.phtml">Shops</a><a href="/mall/index.phtml">Mall</a><a href="/~Sparkle">Credit</a>
</div>
<br><div style="width: 800px;">

</div>
```

Comment: There are two ways to position an `img`: 1. use `position:absolute` or 2. move it up in your HTML code (ie. out of the `table` and into `div.main` or `div.content`)

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
img.special { position: absolute; top: 0; }
body { margin-top: 274px; }
```

I added this using [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and it worked for me.

What this is doing:

- First, it's absolutely positioning the image, (specifying that specific image using the correct class name — `.special`)
- Second, it moves the image to the top, by setting top to `0`.  This only works because the image is absolutely positioned.
- Third, it shifts the entire website down by adding a `top-margin` to the page that is equal to the height of the image.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Sorry but where do I put this in the code? I got the margin part I believe but where do I put the first line? Whoever changed my code above, it didn't work, but it changed back now.

Comment: It's CSS, so try adding it to the bottom of the `<style>` block, just before `</style>`.

Comment: ALMOST! :P I put the line just before the </Style> Go back to the website of the userlookup of what it is now, doesn't seem to want to leave the box :S I doesn't even really have to leave the box as long as it looks like it is out of it. So maybe extend the picture to kinda float over the border. Also the part where it said "Userlookup: Cool_xman" was above the picture before but I want it to be below the pic. Thanks a lot for helping me :)

Comment: It looks like the HTML was modified since I sent you the original code.  It worked before.